# Android Quiz logic/coding 

Tags: java, android

I have made a quiz using actionscript. I have begun working on the quiz in android (complete newbie), following the actionscripts as away of getting my head around the logic.

i don't know how to approach the change_question function, Particularly this first chunk. below.

```
  function change_question(){
  if(tick.visible){
     right_answers++;
  }
  if(cross.visible){
     wrong_answers++;
  }
  if(qno==questions.length){
       gotoAndPlay(2);
   }else{
  tick.visible=false;
  cross.visible=false;
  rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
  rnd2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
  q.text=questions[rnd2];
  if(questions[rnd2]=="x"){
  change_question();
  }
  questions[rnd2]="x";
  enable_disable(1);
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Here is my android code so far!

```
package ks3.mathsapp.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MathsMultiplicationActivity extends Activity {


TextView quesnum;
TextView ques;
TextView anst;
TextView ans1;
TextView ans2;
TextView ans3;
TextView ans4;
ImageView cross;
ImageView tick;


    int qno = 0;
    int right_answers = 0;
    int wrong_answers = 0;
    int rnd1;
    int rnd2;

    String [] questions = {"How much mph does the F-Duct add to the car?",
              "What car part is considered the biggest performance variable?",
              "What car part is designed to speed up air flow at the car rear?",
              "In seconds, how long does it take for a F1 car to stop when travelling at 300km/h?",
              "How many litres of air does an F1 car consume per second?",
              "What car part can heavily influence oversteer and understeer?",
              "A third of the cars downforce can come from what?",
              "Around how much race fuel would be consumed per 100km?","The first high nose cone was introduced when?",
              "An increase in what, has led to the length of exhaust pipes being shortened drastically?"};

    String [] [] answers = {{"3","5","8","9"},
    {"Tyres","Front Wing","F-Duct","Engine"},
    {"Diffuser","Suspension","Tyres","Exhaust"},
    {"4","6","8","10"},
    {"650","10","75","450"},
    {"Suspension","Tyres","Cockpit","Chassis"},
    {"Rear Wing","Nose Cone","Chassis","Engine"},
    {"75 Litres","100 Litres","50 Litres","25 Litres"},
    {"1990","1989","1993","1992"},
    {"Engine RPM","Nose Cone Lengths","Tyre Size","Number of Races"}};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multiplechoice);


    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    quesnum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNum);
    ques = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    anst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answertit);
    ans1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
    ans2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
    ans3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
    ans4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    cross = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cross);
    tick = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tick);

    cross.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    tick.setVisibility(View.GONE); 



        if(rnd1==1){
            TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
            quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[0]) ;            

            TextView quesAns2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2); 
            quesAns2.setText("2) " + answers[1]) ;   

            TextView quesAns3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
            quesAns3.setText("3) " + answers[2]) ;   

            TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4); 
            quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[3]) ;   
        }

        if(rnd1==2){
            TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
            quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[2]) ;            

            TextView quesAns2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2); 
            quesAns2.setText("2) " + answers[0]) ;   

            TextView quesAns3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
            quesAns3.setText("3) " + answers[1]) ;   

            TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4); 
            quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[3]) ;  
        }
        if(rnd1==3){
            TextView quesAns1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1); 
            quesAns1.setText("1) " + answers[1]) ;            

            TextView quesAns2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2); 
            quesAns2.setText("2) " + answers[2]) ;   

            TextView quesAns3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3); 
            quesAns3.setText("3) " + answers[0]) ;   

            TextView quesAns4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4); 
            quesAns4.setText("4) " + answers[3]) ;  
        }


    }


    }
```

---

This is the action script model i have been using to help with the logic.

```
  var qno=0;var rnd1; var rnd2;
  tick.visible=false;cross.visible=false;
  var right_answers=0;var wrong_answers=0;

  function change_question(){
  if(tick.visible){
     right_answers++;
  }
  if(cross.visible){
     wrong_answers++;
  }
  if(qno==questions.length){
       gotoAndPlay(2);
   }else{
  tick.visible=false;
  cross.visible=false;
  rnd1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*3);
  rnd2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*questions.length)-1;
  q.text=questions[rnd2];
  if(questions[rnd2]=="x"){
  change_question();
  }
  questions[rnd2]="x";
  enable_disable(1);

  if(rnd1==1){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][1];opt3.text=answers[rnd2][2];opt4.text=answers[rnd2][3];} 
  if(rnd1==2){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][2];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt3.text=answers[rnd2][1];opt4.text=answers[rnd2][3];} 
  if(rnd1==3){opt1.text=answers[rnd2][1];opt2.text=answers[rnd2][2];opt3.text=answers[rnd2][0];opt4.text=answers[rnd2][3];} }} 

  function enable_disable(a){ 
  if(a==0)   {shade1.mouseEnabled=false;shade2.mouseEnabled=false;shade3.mouseEnabled=false;shade4.mouseEnabled=false;} 
  if(a==1){shade1.mouseEnabled=true;shade2.mouseEnabled=true;shade3.mouseEnabled=true;shade4.mouseEnabled=true;}}

change_question();

next_b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction1); 
function ButtonAction1(eventObject:MouseEvent) {qno++;change_question();} 

shade1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction2); 
shade2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction3); 
shade3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction4);
shade4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction5);

 function ButtonAction2(eventObject:MouseEvent){enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==1){      tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade1.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade1.y}}
 function ButtonAction3(eventObject:MouseEvent){enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==2){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade2.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade2.y}}
 function ButtonAction4(eventObject:MouseEvent){enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==3){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade3.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade3.y}}
 function ButtonAction5(eventObject:MouseEvent){enable_disable(0);if(rnd1==4){tick.visible=true;tick.y=shade4.y}else{cross.visible=true;cross.y=shade4.y}}


stop();
```

Comment: Oh my! Do you always write code like that?  How about line breaks and indentation?

Comment: sorry, i have made a few changes. Hopefully that makes it a little bit easier to read. Was difficult copying it all in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you a few point (I'll edit them into this answer as I go, in absolutely no logical order).

- When you define your individual `rnd`s, set your questions in a member `TextView[]`.  This way you don't how so many call to `findViewById()` and if get to know the [enhanced for-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) in java this will save you a lot of code.
- `shade1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ButtonAction2);` will become

  ```
  shade1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
          buttonAction2();
      }
  };
  ```
- you found the `setVisibilty()` and `getVisibility()`, if you simply want to disable onClick events on other elements you can use `setEnabled(true | false)`

Hope that helps move you along.

Comment: Thanks sam i have begun working on the code again. I will post what i have done in the main question soon.

Thanks!